# AngularJS multiple controllers on the same page - Only the first one works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Previously I had a similar question, but this time, following all guidelines of AngularJS, I can't understand what goes wrong.

I have an index.html file with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body ng-app="sportcial">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-person" ui-sref="profile">
        <ion-nav-view name="profile">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="icon-cashier" ui-sref="signin">
        <ion-nav-view name="signin"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-search" ui-sref="search">
        <ion-nav-view name="search"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="icon-messages" ui-sref="messages">
        <ion-nav-view name="messages"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
        <button ng-click="openPopover($event)">Menu</button>
    </ion-tabs>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MenuController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/SigninController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/WelcomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/ProfileController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've omitted other inclusions in head and before closing body tag, they are not breaking anything.

My app.js bootstraps the application like:

```
var app = angular.module('sportcial', ['ionic']);

app.run(function run($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, FACEBOOK_APP_ID) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if (!window.cordova) {
            facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
        }

        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

config.js, routes.js, services.js are not redeclaring the main module.

They are all of the same concept:

```
app.config(function configApp($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
});
```

Reusing the app instance.

So the issue is with having multiple controllers, where only the first one instantiating itself and the others are ignored.

Here are my controllers:

Home works:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function HomeController($scope) {
    alert(1); // works
});
```

This one already not:

```
app.controller('MenuController', function MenuController($scope, $ionicPopover) {
    alert(2);

    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('../views/menu.html', {
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function(popover) {    
        $scope.popover = popover;
    });

    $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
        $scope.popover.show($event);
    };

    $scope.closePopover = function() {
        $scope.popover.hide();
    };

    //Cleanup the popover when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.popover.remove();
    });

    // Execute action on hide popover
    $scope.$on('popover.hidden', function() {
        // Execute action
    });

    // Execute action on remove popover
    $scope.$on('popover.removed', function() {
        // Execute action
    });
});
```

Any ideas what I screwed up here?

Thanks

Comment: I dont see anywhere your controller is being used!

Comment: Can you show your html code for controllers

Comment: I'm talking about the instantiation issue first. I will start using it when it's actually loaded. I removed the logic and usage to test if a bare controller will work. They are loaded via script tag, not ng-controller directive, still other controllers MUST react the same way as HomeController. They should fire alert function

Comment: It is not necessary that alert in 2nd controller should fire unless you are using it in the html

Comment: I've added MenuController.js's full contents. The usage of it is in the index.html button's ng-click directive: openPopover($event). This is what I'm trying to achieve. Open a popover with nested view.

Comment: @Sajeetharan is it an issue with redefining $scope in every controller?

Comment: @Fratyr It's not an issue, i think you must read/understand about the concept of using controllers

Comment: @Sajeetharan oh, my bad. I'm using stateProvider to bind routes to controllers. But then, each view have only one active controller and if I need to add another one without specifying it with ng-directive, how can I make it active under the same route statement? The problem is I want to have my MenuController be global on every single view.

Comment: Just put the MenuController on the html , ng-controller = "MenuController"

Comment: @fratyr, please reformulate the question stating your requirements and needs. what you mentioned in your last comment should be listed in the question in greater detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about the lifecycle of a controller and where a certain controller is available: "A controller controls a view"!

A controller definition like `module.controller('ctrlname', fn)` just defines a controller function. Important: This controller function will not be run with this yet, it just makes it known to the angular environment by the name you give it, eg. 'ctrlname' here. It is also not yet defined, where this controller will be run.

You must then associate your controller with a view (= a DOM element = a HTML Partial = a template) that it is controlling. You can do this in several ways:

1. use `ng-controller` to associate it directly
2. use ui-router (or ng-router) states definition: it will associate the controller you define with the top level tag in the view (=template) you are defining in the state.
3. in a directive definition.
4. maybe others?...

The controller function is then run as soon as that element/Partial/template where you assiciated it to is rendered.

The $scope that is injected into each of these controllers inherit from each other whenever the tag a controller is associated to is nested inside another tag that holds another controller. This prototypical inheritence is a way to access data of a controller's scope from another controller, that lives on a child element.

You can also use the `controller as ctrlName` syntax. This allows you the give your controller a name and lets you directly access any parent controller by its name you give it from the HTML templates (as long as you are nested deeper).

So, if I understand your need correctly, you want to have the Menu always visible (in multiple ui-router states). The right solution is therefore to just associate the controller that controls that menu with the top-level HTML tag of the menu by using `ng-controller` in the HTML.